# strip out everything out side of <img src=random.jpg> and <p>random text</p> in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, iis, httpmodule

I am trying to strip data out of a web page using a c# http module. I just want **raw text and images**. How can I strip everything else out?

```
private static Regex reg = new Regex(@"<img src=\t????????");

public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
      byte[] data = new byte[count];
      Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
      string html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

      html = reg.Replace(html, string.Empty);


      byte[] outdata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
      _sink.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
    }
```

Comment: [obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Blender - An HTML parser would be a better choice.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not an exact duplicate, but the accepted answer still answers this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: that thread is spammed to high hell. Any other solutions, such as which XMl parser to use???

Comment: We're not spamming you. Read the responses to the linked questions to see *why* you don't parse HTML/XML with regex. @Oded, I don't even know a bit of C#, and in Python, there's only an XML parser :P

Comment: @user719825 This is a Q&A site, *not* a forum. Using `???` won't speed up getting a *good* answer.

Comment: @Blender - Fair enough. Most XML parsers will choke on good HTML unless it was specifically written as XML.

Comment: @user719825 - Comments are not answers.

Comment: @Oded: Really? I thought HTML was a subset of XML, so an XML parser would parse HTML also. I'd better read up on that...

Comment: @Blender, HTML does is often not valid XML. Consider the simple case of `<br>`, which is perfectly legal for browsers, but for it to be valid XML, would need a closing. `<br />`.

Comment: Im using htmlagilitypack now, but I can only get it to load via an actual page. How would I take the data in a buffer (before the page renders on the browser?)

Comment: @Blender: You're probably thinking of XHTML, which is the other way around (XHTML is a subset of XML).

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Yep, that's what my `<!DOCTYPE>` says. *Successful question subject diversion!*

Comment: Lol :)  @user719825: Don't use an XML parser unless you want to verify standard conformance, and are sure all your documents (should) be valid XHTML: See the difference between SGML-based HTML and XML-based HTML here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#SGML-based_versus_XML-based_HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML parser, such as the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Im using that now, but I can only get it to load via an actual page. How would I take the data in a buffer (before the page renders on the browser?)

Comment: Is there a `Render` method you could override? (Can't remember if that's just for `Page`s or not).